# Full text search in appengine, make some fields scores more important than others?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have a python appengine app that uses full text search.  The document model has something like

title: title
abstract: short abstract
full text: lots and lots of text

If someone searches for a string, I want it ordered such that score for matches in title >> abstract >> full text.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the exiting scoring options, am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately yes; we don't yet have a way for you to weight different fields more or less than others. Sorry!